# Modal not validating when elements generated through external file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've been experimenting with modal dialogue boxes and came across one which uses the FancyBox JQuery tool. I am trying to understand why the validation script works correctly when the modal elements are in HTML form on the same page (in the body tags) as the script, however if I generate these elements in a php file the validation script fails.

Please see my index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-modal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="like2.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".load").load('show.php');

        function validateEmail(email) { 
            var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return reg.test(email);
        }

        $(".modalbox").fancybox();

        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });

        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var commentid = $("#commentid").val();

            alert("clicked!");

            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true) {
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>Sending...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
   });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="load">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please see the php file "show.php" which I load:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

echo '<div class="load">

<button class="modalbox" href="#inline">Click</button>

</div>

<div id="inline">
<h3>Enter your email to receive updates</h3>
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
<label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
            <input type="hidden" id="commentid" name="commentid" value="5">
<br>
<button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>';
?>
```

In this format when I click "Click" on index.php, the modal appears as normal, however when I click "Send E-mail" with or without data, the modal fades without any feedback or validation. Is it possible to work with this set up? All works as expected when the contents of div id="inline" from show.php are put into the body of index.html. Please assist

Comment: Why are you creating show.php and load it in index.php? Place it directly in index.php.

Comment: @Indrasinh Bihola - I did so as I had multiple buttons which trigger the modal and wanted to have a unique ID variable for each button. I then wanted to send the ID of the clicked button to a database. The actual php file I have contains a loop which echoes out a string and a button for each string. I couldn't see how to achieve this through just including it in the index.php file.

Comment: Ok So When you click on Send E-mail. Is the page gets refreshed?